# DBT Validation for Date with (yyyy-mm-dd) format

Tags: dbt, dbtype

I would like to ask for your assistance because I'm currently having difficulties to implement date validation with this format (yyyy-mm-dd) I tried to use this command below, unfortunately I'm getting an error. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_match_regex:
          regex: "^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

Comment: Can you share the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is in the style of a raw string (you aren't doubling your backslashes). You need to add an argument to the test definition to tell dbt_expectations to parse it as a raw string:

```yaml
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_match_regex:
          regex: "^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
          is_raw: True
```

Alternatively, you could double all the backslashes:

```yaml
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_match_regex:
          regex: "^\\d{4}\\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

Docs are [here](https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations#expect_column_values_to_match_regex).